# App crashed in iOS8 beta4 and beta5 because of Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios8

App crashed in iOS8 beta4, when I set NSLayoutConstraints for view between NSLayoutAttributeLeading and NSLayoutAttributeLeft attributes.

This happens in all scenarios , when we add constraints for view of the  described combination.

```
NSLayoutAttributeLeading and NSLayoutAttributeRight
NSLayoutAttributeTrailing and NSLayoutAttributeRight
NSLayoutAttributeLeading and NSLayoutAttributeLeft
```

This set of code works fine in iOS7.0 , it crashes in iOS8 beta4 and beta5 alone.

Is this an issue? Or we should not set constraints as mentioned in my description.
Kindly let me know if anyone faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, NSLayoutAttributeLeading and NSLayoutAttributeLeft are same for a Left-to-right language mode. But for an RTL language like Arabic, NSLayoutAttributeLeading will actually mean right. This is why you shouldn't try to construct constraints NSLayoutAttributeLeading & NSLayoutAttributeTrailing  with Left & Right. In iOS 7 it wouldn't crash, but seems like iOS 8 has gotten more strict in this case.

While both of the following works and results in similar behaviour, the second one will crash in iOS8 (the last I checked is in beta 5)
//iOS8 way (works fine in iOS7)

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:10.0f]

//iOS7 way (may crash in iOS8)

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:10.0f]

Thanks